# Does apache_beam Python SDK 0.6.0 BigQuerySink support table partitions?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have been prototyping a beam pipeline using their python SDK and have been able to use the BigQuerySink to output my final pcollection just fine using this:

```
     beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink('dataset.table', 
                                self.get_schema(),
       create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,                                               
     write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE))
```

modifying the table to include a partition such as this: `dataset.table$20170517` triggers the following error when trying to run this pipeline with the DirectRunner

---

"code": 400,
  "message": "Cannot read partition information from a table that is not partitioned:

---

I have studied the examples found here but found no trace of partition use
https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples

How can beam sink data into partitioned bigquery tables?

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems like table partitions are actually supported. (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-0.6.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L268). Is your table properly partitioned? I'm checking to see if DirectRunner supports the operation.

Comment: Is your table actually partitioned?

Comment: @pablo @Graham Polley: Yes the table is partitioned. When I `bq show` the table I get  
        "timePartitioning": {
                "type": "DAY"
         } 

Now after I execute my pipeline and load data without specifying the partition, then the partition information gets removed. It's as if the BigQuerySink removes the partitioning from the table.

Answer (score 1):

The apache_beam Python SDK does accept partition decorators for the BigQuerySink. Experimenting with the different write_disposition available reveals more information.

- WRITE_TRUNCATE will not write to table partitions. Using the $YYYYmmdd partition in the table name will result in this error. This differs from the Google Python SDK behaviour which will actually accept the partition decorator.

  ```
  Table IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and 
  must be at most 1024 characters long.
  ```
- WRITE_EMPTY will accept the partition decorator.
- WRITE_APPEND will accept the partition decorator.